# Reading lines from a encrypted file based on a delimeter java

Tags: java, string, file-io

I have an file containing encrypted Json Strings, i am using AES encryption with padding, i have another class which reads these files as input and decrypts the encrypted Json Strings, the problem i am facing is the encrypted json string is being written on multiple lines like

```
TRX+s0CJYKyKnUJFrFpG77GRxQBDqj4diJhEEmP2sPO0RkgZNeR0acPftfj85ef7WA0ty078rPvk
l3GTb8blA9ytd/SXkaGbp37pLIZilSYoyHTMy/Dd+GiNommta/aqPd5v0CRPda4lKf3tQgGBAw==
```

i am using Java 8 to read string using File.lines(path), this is giving me only the first line of the encrypted string, instead i need the entire encrpted string to be read into a string object, is there a way to specify different delimiter for File.lines()?. Also please note that the actual encrypted string spans around 10 lines, and the file has large number of documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here's what i did, I wrote the encrypted strings with a delimiter "," and then used scanner to read from the file, the code goes as below

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(File);
x.setDelimeter(",");
while(x.hasNext()){
decrypt(x.next());
}
```

Answer 2: Use a different encoder which doesn't add new lines to the encrypted string, and use the existing File.readLine() method. i used commons io codec base64 encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your output.

```
string.replaceAll(".*\\R.*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Files.lines(path)` method itself does not allow for a different delimiter. If you want to retain a similar code style to what you currently have, I would read the file into a single string this way:

```
String encrypted ="";
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(path)) encrypted += line;
```

This will fill the string with every line in turn, removing the newlines. If you want them to stay, add them back manually: `encrypted += line + "\n";`

That being said, if your method of writing to a file is causing newlines to appear in the file, and you don't want any newlines in the file, the first thing you should re-evaluate is that output, rather than adjusting your method of reading.